# Making contact me form

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm making a webpage and I wanna make a contact me form too. I've downloaded a template with fields 'name','email' and 'message' and 'send' button. I've read a couple of guides, but form is never sent.

Can you help me, please? Thanks!

my code:

Comment: Share your tried codes

Comment: Can u please show me the code you have written or tried

Comment: show your template code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me help you in this level.

Assuming your contact page is like this

```
<title>Contact Form</title>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><strong>Contact Form </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="200" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="contact_ac.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="cmail" type="text" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="16%">Subject</td>
<td width="2%">:</td>
<td width="82%"><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Detail</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea name="detail" cols="50" rows="4" id="detail"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The Contact Page's Action

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$cmail=$_POST['cmail'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$header="from: $name <$cmail";
$to ='yourmail@yourdomain.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
if($send_contact){
echo "We've recived your contact information";
}
else {
    echo "Error Sending Mail";
    }
?>
```

Note : Replace     `$to ='yourmail@yourdomain.com';` with your email.

Comment: Thank you! I'd give you 1 up, but I haven't got any reputation yet, sorry :(